# Java Problem in configuration

Tags: java

[image: javac is not displaying]

Hi friends, in this image java is installed on my computer and when i use the " java -version " shows me the message diplayed in the image . But, when I use javac -version this show me error " not found " why is this so and how to properly set java on my computer so as to use this for my programming compiling and executing java files.
Thanks in advance !!

I installed openjdk as well:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you see there ,you have installed Java Run time Environment which is actually needed to run Java based software in your system.

for example If you place `java filename` then it will execute that particular java file.

but javac belongs JDK which stands for Java development Kit , which you need If you would like to do programming on Java.

To get install Java for programming you can install openjdk-7-jdk with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: @grv.giit friend Open JDK Runtime environment states that only .

Comment: :- can i compile my java files by : javac <filename>.java now ??

Comment: If you got Java runtime environment then you can do only Java <filename>.If you would like to do javac <filename>.java  then you have to install what i have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @grv.giit you see the comment.

Comment: @snow- How do I compile when i have not set the path and classpath here .. please reply  :)